# Style a substring in javascript

Tags: javascript, styles, substring

Hi i am trying to style a substring with javascript. Here's my code:

```
function runtest(){
    document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML.substring(0,2).style.fontStyle="italic";
}
```

The substring function works but when I add the style the error console gives me an error of "undefined." How can I style this substring with javascript?

Comment: Wrap it in a `span`, add a class, and style that.

Comment: Only elements have a style property, a string does not.

Comment: now that I added a style to the span(I styled it using javascript), it will not print out the substring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options:

1. An `innerHTML` solution. **Warning**: This will remove any event handlers on any elements within the element you're doing it on. I mention it here mostly so I can point that out:

   ```
   var elm = document.getElementById("test1");
   var html = elm.innerHTML;
   elm.innerHTML = '<span style="font-style: italic">' + html.substring(0, 2) + '</span>' + html.substring(2);
   ```
2. Using [`splitText`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-38853C1D). Here I'm assuming the text you want to wrap in a span is the *first* text node within the element. This *won't* mess up event handlers on the elements:

   ```
   var elm = document.getElementById("test1");
   var node = elm.firstChild;
   var span = document.createElement('span');
   node.splitText(2);
   span.style.fontStyle = "italic";
   elm.insertBefore(span, node);
   span.appendChild(node);
   ```

   `splitText` creates two adjacent text nodes where there used to be one, with the split point being at the offset you specify. Then we take the first one and wrap it in a `span`.

   [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/epamox/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/epamox/1/edit)