# Styling Substring between two characters?

Tags: javascript, css, string, substring

I'm getting a substring that's between two characters in an input label.
this label is received as @input in a shared angular component and not all labels have the same structure

```
this.label = Address* (number and type);

  styleSublabel() {
    if (this.label.includes('(')) {
      const mySubString = this.label.substring(
this.label.lastIndexOf('('),
this.label.lastIndexOf(')') + 1);      
    }
  }
```

my intention is to give a different style of css with which to put a smaller font-size and italic style to this substring but I don't see a way to do it.
Is it possible?
Greetings and thanks in advance
Is it possible?
Greetings and thanks in advance

Comment: Wrap that part in span with specific style

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048025/style-a-substring-in-javascript

Comment: @Justinas the problem is that the label is received as input in a shared angular component and not all labels have the same structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can surround it by a div for example and give it a class with the style you want.

for example

```
<div class="styled-label"> {mySubString} </div>
```

and in CSS

```
.styled-label{
   font-style: italic;
   font-size: 0.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?
Before the substring put

```
"<span class='styleSub'>"
```

and after the substring put

```
"</span>"
```

In your css file put

```
.styleSub
{
color: #eee;
}
```

When you get that working you can changed the styling to anything you want.